# Perl: What type should be used for class object in "validate" function

Tags: perl, validation

I want to pass the reference of class object called "A" in constructor. And use "validate" function to check it.

like that:

test1.pm

```
my $object = Object1->new;

my $newObject = Object2->new({
    param1 => $object,
});
```

test2.pm

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my (%options) = validate (@_, {
        param1 => { type => SCALARREF, default => undef},
    });
    ...
}
```

The problem that I'm not sure about the type of the parameter param1. I tried "OBJECT" and "SCALARREF" but there were errors like "SCALARREF not allowed while strict sub".

What type should I use?

Answer (score 2):

It looks you're trying to do a quasi-[`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) thing here. But in Moose, you don't create `new` subs, because [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) does that for you. If you need anything--you create a `BUILD` sub.

The Perl (5) base object system doesn't work like Moose, so `'SCALARREF'` or whatever is what you make it in base Perl.

- Do you realize that you are passing a hashref to `new`?
- Do you realize that vaildate is getting two hashrefs?
   
  `validate( {}, {} )`

And if `SCALARREF` has not been defined, it will always be a bareword.

Read up on [`Moose`](http://www.iinteractive.com/moose/). You can start with the [Moose Types Manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aTypes), to see how `ScalarRef` is used, but since you don't even show "`use Moose`", you should start at page 1 of the [Manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual).

Comment: I just sorted it. I should use  "use Params::Validate qw(:all);" and use "Object type". Now it works ok)